# how to get query parameter in lua or nginx?

Tags: nginx, lua, query-string, url-shortener, request.querystring

I am trying to implement this-
https://gist.github.com/MendelGusmao/2356310
Lua,nginx based URL shortener,The only change i want to implement is when some query string parameter comes with shortened URL i need to take that parameter and insert into the long URL.

e.g.
http://google.com?test=2  will be like  http://abc.in/abc
while hitting on http://abc.in/abc?test=3 I get redirected to - http://google.com?test=3.

For that i need to take query string parameters from $request_URI, can any one help with some code?

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_uri_args

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should be able to use `ngx.var.arg_name` where `name` is the name of the query parameter you want to access. See [Variables with Infinite Names section in this tutorial](http://openresty.org/download/agentzh-nginx-tutorials-en.html#01-nginxvariables02) for details on query parameter handling; you may also check my [blog post](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-openresty-nginx-lua-scripts-with-zerobrane-studio) for Lua nginx/openresty examples.

As an alternative, you can use `ngx.req.get_uri_args()` to retrieve all query parameters as one table. See [this section](http://openresty.org/download/agentzh-nginx-tutorials-en.html#01-nginxvariables07) in the same tutorial for the brief comparison between these methods.

Comment: How does the table returned by `get_uri_args` differ from the table referred to by `ngx.var.args`?

Comment: `ngx.var` allows retrieving individual arguments when you know their names (through the use of metafields, these values actually don't exist in the table); `get_uri_args()` allows retrieving all passed arguments.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `ngx.var.QUERY_STRING` to access the query string and unescape and parse it.

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain the query parameter with just nginx by using `$arg_test`, `test` is the name of the query parameter in this example.

This is documented in http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_.